# How to identify beginning of an event

Tags: pine-script

I have 2 moving averages and I want to identify this event :

```
begin = close > ma(close,50)
ending = close < ma(close,500)
```

So my event starts when close is over MA50 and the event ends when close is under ma500.  Is there a simple way to do that? I'm a bit lost with the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Event", "EV", true)

source                      = input(close, "Source",       type=input.source)
var int     sma_len_1       = input(13,    "SMA Length 1", minval=1)
var int     sma_len_2       = input(30,    "SMA Length 2", minval=1)
var bool    event_active    = na

sma1 = sma(source, sma_len_1)
sma2 = sma(source, sma_len_2)

if crossover(source, sma1)
    event_active := true

if crossunder(source, sma2)
    event_active := false

plot(sma1, "SMA1", color.red)
plot(sma2, "SMA2", color.blue)

bgcolor(event_active ? color.lime : na)
```